# Repetitive logic

Tags: r, loops, forecasting, arima

I have written a code that takes sets of data from an excel sheet and run some forecasting commands. After that I save the graphs at a location on my desktop. The code works perfectly. I was wondering if there is a way that I can loop these commands on every element(column) of the sheet and then have R save the required graphs in my desired location.

Thanks

Comment: An obvious input solution is to read the entire worksheet into R as a dataframe/matrix and then loop through every column.  Your question about saving the graphs is not clear.  As R outputs and in what format?  Or exported to Excel as separate worksheets or workbooks?

Comment: Saving graphs as images

Comment: Save plot in R: https://r-coder.com/save-plot-r/  See the section: Saving many plots at once in R  Note that you can save a lot of time by first doing a web search yourself.  E.g. r export graph turns up useful links.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.